# Java code for to accept 7 bit ascii characters

Tags: java, regex

I wanted code to accept all 7 bit ascii character set but not to accept 8bit characters. I have tried with regular expression:

```
user.getFirstName()).matches("[\\w\\s]+")
```

Comment: You won't succed with regexp because regexp have nothing to do with ascii encoding. You should convert your character to a byte array (specifying the encding you want) and check this byte array.

Comment: You could go over the String and look at each character to see if it has a codepoint < 128.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Java Regular Expressions class for this set. It is `\p{ASCII}`. See [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

```
 "ABC".matches("\\p{ASCII}+") == true;
 "ABCŻ".matches("\\p{ASCII}+") == false;
```

Comment: +1 for pointing this out - although i have worked with Java regexes sometimes, i just realised that i missed a lot of its many options! Looks like Java is the better Perl :-)

Comment: "Looks like Java is the better Perl" How can you say that in the face of the double-backslash? ;-)

Comment: @PaulGorbas It is [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Yep - MATCH is JavaScript and MATCHES is JAVA, sorry missed the language in a false search result.

Answer (score 3):

There is the '\x' way of entering numbers hexadecimally: (Source http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html )

```
yourString.matches("[\\x00-\\x7F]+");
```

In Java this might be:

```
yourString.matches("[\\u0000-\\u007F]+");
```

Comment: One backslash, not two, suffices. One may use such a notation everywhere in a java source, for instance to have nice Javadoc with a math formula, copyright symbol or whatever.